# Output the slug and name of a CPT single post taxonomy term

Tags: custom-post-types, terms

When I'm on a single post for a custom post type, I want to be able to grab the `slug` and `name` of the taxonomy term so I can insert them into a link. Below is what I've tried but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<?php

$term_slug = get_queried_object()->slug;
$term_name = get_queried_object()->name;

echo '<span class="back-button"><a href="/portfolio/' .$term_slug. '">&larr; Back to ' .$term_name. '</a></span>';

?>
```

So for example, if I'm on a single post for the custom post type "Projects" and the taxonomy term is "Album Artwork," I want to be able to grab the `slug` "album-artwork" and the name "Album Artwork" so I can put them into the link. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you’re on a single post, then your code won’t work, because `get_queried_object` will contain the post (and not a term).

If you want to get terms of given post, you should use [`get_the_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) function.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), '<TAXONOMY_NAME>' ); // <- put real tax name in here
```

You also have to remember, that a post may have multiple terms assigned to it, so the line above will get you an array of terms. You can loop through it like so:

```
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
     echo '<span class="back-button"><a href="/portfolio/' .$term->slug. '">&larr; Back to ' .$term->name. '</a></span>';
}
```

And the last thing...

You should never build term links like you do. There is a function for that to: [`get_term_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/) and you should use it instead of concatenating slug of a term with some strings (why? Because some plugins may change the structure of such links and your code will stop working then).

So the full code can look like this:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), '<TAXONOMY_NAME>' ); // <- put real tax name in here
if ( $terms and ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<span class="back-button"><a href="' . esc_attr( get_term_link( $term ) . '">&larr; Back to ' . esc_html($term->name) . '</a></span>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I get the `slug`? The reason is because I don't want the link to go to the taxonomy link. I have my own link with "example.com/portfolio/`slug`"

Comment: Exactly the same way as you get the name: `$term->slug`